# Ways to simplify remote desktop from another terminal to destination

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I can't directly RDP to remote hosts, instead, I have to RDP to a terminal server and RDP from there to the destination. Is there client/tools that can relay my connection from local and pass through the terminal to the destination? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a [Terminal Services Gateway](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731264%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: What if our terminal server is windows server 2003, and it seems not supporting Terminal Services Gateway. Is there any tools that can do RDP twice?